# How to disable zoom icons on Achartengine

Tags: android, zooming, achartengine

I want to disable the zoom icons on Achartengine but without disable the zoom.

It's that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible: renderer.setZoomButtonsEnabled(false);
It works with 0.7.0. Intermediate 0.7.0 releases are available here: http://www.achartengine.org/download/

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

In 1.0.0 it's

```
 renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
```

http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/DefaultRenderer.html#setZoomButtonsVisible(boolean)